# How to program a complexe images grid with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, grid, graphic

For a portfolio website, I'll have to develop a visual grid of images.

I am now doing tests for this grid.

I have two alternatives:

**1.A simple grid,** with vertical alignments, like the one on this wireframe: http://daviddarx.com/stuffs/work/barbu/wireframe/search/simple.png

There is several plugins to do that, and I could easily develop a custom solution, if necessary. But this grid is a bit too simple and common. I would love to get a more complexe grid like this one:

**2.A complexe grid,** without any vertical or horizontal alignment, like the one on this wireframe: 
http://daviddarx.com/stuffs/work/barbu/wireframe/search/complexe.png

But for this one, I really don't see how to start to develop it, conceptually.
So here are my questions:

-I would love to develop a custom grid, to get exactly what I want. Do you have any advices, strategies, tutorials about how to develop such a grid? Which steps, how to start it, etc...

-If else, do you know any plugin or library which could achieve that?

Thank you in advance for your help!
David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This jQuery plugin might do what you want: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

If that doesn't do it, please explain why and I'll try to see if I can think of a different solution.

Comment: Thank you for you're input, this plugin seems to be great! It is still a bit linear as a grid, but it's way better than the others plugins! I'll try that one and then follow this post if I can't do what I want with! Thank you!

Comment: @daviddarx: it's not a plugin is site. The plugin is masonry.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery plugin masonry. If you want to do it yourself you can use a treemap algorithm but there is also a jQuery plugin treemap.